# Who are these characters from Order of the Phoenix?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, character-identification

Obviously, I'm not talking about Ron and Luna. I'm talking about those encircled ones. I see that they are Slytherin students - in the first picture is an unidentified Slytherin female and the 2nd is an unidentified Slytherin male.

**Who are they? What are their names?**

[image: Unidentified Slytherin female]

[image: Unidentified Slytherin female and males]

Comment: I noticed this is at least the third time you add bare image links in your questions. Unfortunately, SE doesn't recognise them, especially if they're not HTTPS links. Please see [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images) for image editing instructions.

Comment: Not sure about the others but I think the first one might've been [Emmaunel Petit](http://i3.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article2909293.ece/ALTERNATES/s615b/Emmanuel-Petit.jpg)...

Comment: Do you want the character names, or the actor names? For characters, there are none, they'll just be listed as "Slytherin Student", or "Slytherin Girl", or possibly something as vague as "Hogwarts Student". For the actors, well, you'd have to check the entire cast and crew, including uncredited, because they likely won't be, and see which actors played the aforementioned generic "Hogwarts / Slytherin Students".

Comment: The characters name

Answer (score 2):

...we don't know; they don't *have* names. They look like extras - there's a whole crowd of people that we don't know in that scene. We don't know the name of every student in the school - there are always going to be characters that we don't know what their names are, especially in the films, where they very often just use extras that aren't named.

Comment: The good thing is that it's a slytherin student

Answer (score 0):

On the wiki page, there is a blonde Slytherin girl who is [Daphne Greengrass](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Daphne_Greengrass), Draco's future wife's older sister (his future wife being Astoria Greengrass).

In the 'Behind the Scenes' section is this quote linking to the following image.

> This individual is often said to have played Daphne Greengrass in the films, but there has been no link established. In fact, Daphne's blond-haired blue-eyed appearance originates from fanon.

[image: A possible Daphne Greengrass]